# Is there any point to get more than 10 stacks of Lens-Maker's Glasses?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

The Lens-Maker's Glasses applies additive critical chance, meaning at a stack of 10 you will achieve 100% crit chance at all times. This is great because it renders utility items like the Ocular HUD irrelevant by having 100% crit uptime.

[image]

That said, I'm wondering if there's even a point to stack lenses past a stack of 10.  In games like Warframe, going beyond 100% crit entails potentially higher crit damage in a mechanic known as "orange" or "red" crit. However, in RoR2, it seems the only thing criticals apply are double damage, since there is no "crit damage" modifier.

That said, I can't seem to find any discernible benefits for stacking beyond 10 lenses -- it doesn't seem to change my damage at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, anything beyond a stack of 10 yields no additional benefits.

From browsing the datamined source code, it looks like critical hits are a true/false toggle -- if you crit, you deal 2x damage, and nothing more/nothing less.

Meaning 10 Lens-Maker's Glasses are the most you need to maintain 100% crit chance. Going above that amount yields no additional benefit, save for having extra backup should you need to convert it into another item should you need them for 3D printers.